# how to unsubscribe for an observable

Tags: angular, observable, unsubscribe

I have an angular application where I am reading a file and processing it and this processing is part of observable. 
I have a service which returns the observable an (ngbusy:subscription). 
I am subscribing to this observable in my component. The observable is assigned to an ngBusy which displays a spinner.
Now the spinner keeps spinning even after subscribe is complete. I know we need to unsubscribe to the obervable.
But when I unsubscri in the same method where we are subscribing, I don't even see the spinner displayed.
Should we always use ngOndestroy to unsubscribe.

service.ts

```
const obsrv:Observable
obsrv= new Observable((observer) => {    
    // observable execution
    observer.next(this.items)
    observer.complete()
})
```

component.ts

```
processItems() {
    ngbusy  = this.myservice.observable.subscribe(items => {
        //perform some business logic 
    });
    this.myservice.observable.unsubscribe(); //not working here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You must unsubscribe from the subscription, not the observable:

```
processItems() {
    const ngbusy = this.myservice.observable.subscribe(items => {
        // perform some business logic 


        // unsubscribe at some point...
        ngbusy.unsubscribe();
    });

    // this will unsubscribe immediately...
    ngbusy.unsubscribe();

}
```

Comment: @Sebastian, thanks. I think I tried unsubscribing the subscription too. Let me try once more. Can that be done in the same method soon after subscribe code ends.

Comment: You should unsubscribe at a point where you don't need the subscription. If it is outside the method, assign the subscription to a class property instead of a variable. That way you can unsubscribe from anywhere in the class.

Comment: This isn't working for me. The spinner doens't go off.

Answer (score 0):

This is a good approach using **takeuntil** and **ngUnsubscribe**

```js
private ngUnsubscribe: Subject = new Subject();

ngOnInit() {
  this.myThingService
    .getThings()
    .takeUntil(this.ngUnsubscribe)
    .subscribe((things) => console.log(things));
  /* if using lettable operators in rxjs ^5.5.0
      this.myThingService.getThings()
          .pipe(takeUntil(this.ngUnsubscribe))
          .subscribe(things => console.log(things));
      */
  this.myThingService
    .getOtherThings()
    .takeUntil(this.ngUnsubscribe)
    .subscribe((things) => console.log(things));
}
ngOnDestroy() {
  this.ngUnsubscribe.next();
  this.ngUnsubscribe.complete();
}
```